Calculate Li-ion discharge time for two different loads, one after the other

Battery: 2S (2 cell), 7.4 V nominal, 3000 mAh, and 8C max.
CC LED driver: TPS92691
LED string 1 (in series):

I(f) = 1.5 A CC @ V(f) 17 V
As simulated through WEBENCH, the input current required at the power converter (i.e, the current drawn from the battery) is 4.5 A
Connected to power converter for 10 s at 8 Hz, 10% duty cycle


LED string 2 (in series):

1 A @ 18 V
As simulated through WEBENCH, again the input current required at the power converter is 3 A
Connected to power converter for n min, steady state output after the above 10 s


The loads are LED strips, hence the LED driver, which is 85% efficient. I aim to strobe Load 1 for 10 s and then have steady illumination for Load 2 for at least 30 minutes to at most 1.5 hours. I want to calculate a rough estimate of how long I can illuminate the load
2. Unsure how to approach estimating the voltage drop of Vbatt after the 10 s and hence consequent remaining energy of the battery. If I know that, then it'd be easy to make a rough estimate of how long I can run Load 2 with the remaining battery capacity.

There is nothing clear about any of this. Please add clarity on what you are trying to do. The very first line is obscure "2S 3000mAh 8C battery - constant current power converter - LOAD"

Ok, sorry about that; I'll edit for more clarity.

@MOSFET edited, I hope this adds more clarity

Still not clear at all but better. First, what are your loads? Also, why are your loads being powered by a LED driver? And what are the specs for the LED driver? The efficiency of the LED driver is paramount for whatever you're trying to do regarding battery run time. It would be best if you describe why you are trying to do what you are trying to do. This seems like your asking for a solution to the wrong problem.

@MOSFET reworded it; I hope this makes sense. I made the mistake of not getting into the details as I didn't want to move away from the core question - calculating discharge characteristics for two different loads. Learnt that it just made the question even more obscure.

You say LOAD 1: 1.5A @ 17V. The next line says your simulation requires 4.5A. So which one is it? That's a big difference. And again, from your diagram, the only "load" the battery sees is this LED driver. This needs explaining or nothing can be calculated. Let's start with are the "loads" on the LED driver strings of LEDs?

@MOSFET So, I've stated two currents. The LED string current / Load current, i.e., 1.5A, and the required input current for the power converter which is the peak current draw that the battery will see. I understand that the battery will only see the power converter as the load, so initially Load 1 is essentially the LED driver + LED string 1 for a fixed 10s at 10% duty cycle, and then it will be switched over to Load 2 which is the LED driver + LED string 2 for a duration I want to estimate for a steady 1A  led current supply or 1A*18V i.e., a steady 18W load.

How did this work out?

Still ambiguous - is the 3000mAh spec for one cell? Or one pack? I'll assume it's for the whole pack for the analysis (the solution will be doubled if this assumption is wrong). I'm also going to assume 3.7V volts per cell considering you never stated that.
This can be figured out in two ways: the charge depleted from the battery or the energy transferred from the battery. I will do this via the energy method. Your fundamental equation is going to be:
Battery Energy = Energy(LOAD1) + Energy(LOAD2)
(3.7V x 2) x 3000mAh = (4.5A x 7.4V x (10% x 10s)) + (7.4V x 3A x mins)
22.2Wh = 32.4Ws + (22.2W x mins)
correcting dimensions to Ws AKA Joules:
79,920Ws = 32.4Ws + (22.2W x t)  where "t" = unknown time in seconds.
Solve for t:
79,887.6Ws = 22.2W x t
t = 3,598.5 seconds, or 1 hour.
This will double to 2 hours if the battery cappacity was in fact 2 x 3000mAh pack capacity.

This is a very ideal calculation. Is there any way to attribute the discharge characteristic of a lithium-ion battery - where it's not a linear discharge? I've read about Peukart's law but have no idea how to use it.

Also, you're right about the battery; I see that I left too many to be assumed parameters. The nominal voltage of the pack is 7.4V hence, 3.7V per cell.  The 3000mAh rating is for the whole pack.

This is the best we could do with the information provided. I'm pretty sure Peukart's law only applies to lead acid batteries. But I could be wrong - I'm not a chemist. If 8C is the discharge limit, that gives you 24A of current. You are way under that so I would imaging those effects would be minimal. Of course, you lose capacity as the cells age. So I would resonably "spec" the run time for 45 - 50 min. Your going to be best measuring this time instead of calculating if you need better approx. than that.

If you can add 1 or 2 more cells, you will get a considerable increase in run time not just from the raw batter capacity, but the LED driver will be much more efficient.

One area of confusion is that once the battery uses more than 1C rating, doesn't the energy capacity drop a lot more? For example, for 2C continuous, the battery can only last for 1/2 hrs. How do you incorporate this factor into the calculation? I feel like there must be an added element in the raw energy calculation to account for the additional energy losses at a higher C rating.

The battery has an internal resistance. You will lose power to current squared because of this. However, the resistance is very low, so even if your losses go up quadratically with current, your resistance is still low. So we usually neglect that fact. But as the current goes up to high current, the i^2 starts to make a real contribution. There may also be chemistry effects inside the electrolyte when you try to diffuse ions too fast. Might want to ask about that as another question. Might get better reception in the chemistry SE

Should the efficiency be a multiplier on the LHS?

Also, shouldn't LHS rather be (8.4-6) * 3000mAh i.e, (Vbatt(max) - Vbatt(min)), thus capturing a more realistic battery capacity.

This answer doesn't quite answer how to theoretically estimate the battery voltage drop after each load. Need it to estimate the depth of discharge after, say, 50min of load2.

Efficiency of what? I don't follow your equation. The battery capacity is a given spec. For the last part: You never asked about battery voltage drop or DOD in your original question. You can estimate DOD by voltage charts for your battery. If all these higher-order effects matter to you, you are obvioulsy hiding important information about your application. Why does any of this matter for powering an LED strip?

Efficiency of the power converter. In your equation, you use 7.43000mAh as the energy of the battery, but that's assuming the whole 7.4V can be used, which is false. A lithium-ion battery can safely be discharged to 6V. Hence the total available energy to use is the max voltage of the battery, i.e., 8.4V - min voltage of the battery, i.e., 6V = 2.4V3000mAh. Isn't that a more realistic calculation of the energy capacity of the battery?

"Unsure how to approach estimating the voltage drop of Vbatt." This indirectly questions the depth of discharge. It matters because this whole question essentially inquires how much time I can supply the second LED strip (load2) with steady current to a safe voltage that won't damage the battery. Understanding the voltage remaining after each load will allow me to estimate how many approximate uses (i.e., a sequence of load 1 + load 2 ) and total cycles, giving me more information that I can use for my application.

Edit: Isn't that a more realistic calculation of the available energy of the battery?

@roaibrain The efficiency of the convertor is already included in the calculation - it's efficiency doesn't even matter; it's only a load that the battery sees independent of its efficiency. Yes, the voltage will drop from 8.4V down to 6V during discharge. 7.4V is the average (AKA the nominal) pack voltage which is why it's used. Again why do all these technicalities even matter? The regulator compensates for all these variations.

The battery variation, and aging, is going to dominate the most perfect theoretical battery discharge model. No engineer would design a system like that. Again, you keep leaving out details of your application that are clearly important if these nit picky battery behaviors matter. If your concerned with run time you have 2 options: Use larger (more) batteries. Or, reduce the current drawn by the convertor. You're trying to make this more complicated.

Okay, I see how efficiency doesn't matter. Hence, isn't the battery's available energy the issue? Doesn't my previous comment answer why I'm curious about those technicalities? Sure, I'm not really going into the specifics of what part of my application requires that kind of information. Can't this be a more general inquiry into estimating certain parameters? Well, I think its best I create another question at this point - I still don't quite understand why I can't ask a question without going into specific application details.

@roaibrain Your previous comment doesn't answer why you're curious about those technicalities because, again, you fail to provide application-specific information on why these things WOULD matter. Everything you presented from the standpoint of the converter DOES NOT MATTER about the technicalities. That's why your application details are important. And, yes, you are going to have to open a new question as this site doesn't like unrelated questions in the comment section. Your question is likely going to get closed otherwise.
